# Set color of highcharts scatter diagram points according to a third value

Tags: highcharts, colors, scatter-plot

I'd like to create a highcharts scatter diagram showing wind direction (y) on a time axis (x). The color of the points should be calculated using the wind speed. How could this be done? The result should look like the attached example, where red dots indicate high speed, green and yellow low speed.

One solution would be to split the data into 12 series (Beaufort 1-12) with different colors, shown in the same chart, but I would prefer to find a method to calculate the colors for each point seperately.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `colorAxis` with `dataClasses` and `colorKey` for the series. For example:

```
  colorAxis: {
    dataClasses: [{
      to: 10,
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      to: 50,
      from: 10,
      color: 'yellow'
    }, {
      to: 100,
      from: 50,
      color: 'red'
    }]
  },
  series: [{
    colorKey: 'speed',
    data: [{
      x: 0,
      y: 1,
      speed: 10
    }, ...],
    type: 'scatter'
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5po1Lqym/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/color-axis

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis.dataClasses